# import multiple txt files into numpy array with column0=datetime objects and column1=float values

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have many text files that look like:

```
#comment
2012-01-01 00:00:00, 6542736.60466
2012-01-01 00:00:05, 6542736.60466
2012-01-01 00:00:10, 6568774.53588
2012-01-01 00:00:15, 6594812.46709
...
2012-01-01 23:59:55, 6494801.44322
```

There is a text file for each day so ultimately I would like to stack the data in the text files in an array so that the times continue seamlessly (eg. from 2012-01-01 23:59:55 to 2012-01-02 00:00:00)

```
monitor1="list of file names in a directory"

for x in monitor1:
    x=np.genfromtxt((filepath+"\\"+x),comments='#',delimiter=',')
monitor1array=np.vstack(monitor1)
for x in monitor1array[:,0]:
    x=datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

This code does not appear to work. 1)it does not seem to be able to create a list of arrays in the first for loop. 2)it does not recognize datetime as the type of column 0.

Help please!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to have a much better experience [reading csvs with pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#csv-text-files):

```
In [11]: import pandas as pd

In [12]: pd.read_csv('foo.csv', header=None, comment='#')
Out[12]:
                     0              1
0  2012-01-01 00:00:00  6542736.60466
1  2012-01-01 00:00:05  6542736.60466
2  2012-01-01 00:00:10  6568774.53588
3  2012-01-01 00:00:15  6594812.46709
```

The dates ought to parse correctly, if not use `pd.to_datetime` on the column:

```
In [13]: df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])
```

Comment: how would I write this in a for loop for all files in monitor1?  There are a lot of files so I can't do the typical df1= pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, comment='#')

Comment: @Solar You could save them as a list (e.g. with a comprehension) and then `pd.concat` them.